# How to fix a 'System.DllNotFoundException' error when running a ArcGIS Runtime WPF App (.NET)?

Tags: wpf, system, arcgis, arcgis-runtime-net

I set up a ArcGIS Runtime WPF App (.NET) in Visual Studios. I tried running the application and a 'System.DllNotFoundException' error occurs. The error more specifically says 'Unable to load DLL "RuntimeCoreNet100_14.WPF.dll" or one of its dependencies'. How do you fix this error? Here is the full error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read the system requirements. The Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019-2022 component needs to be installed
https://developers.arcgis.com/net/get-started/#1-system-requirements

Depending on whether you’re targeting .net framework or .net 6 there could be certain custom property settings you have that prevents deployed the require assemblies. I’d recommend installing the ArcGIS Runtime project templates from the visual studio gallery and try and create a new ArcGIS wpf app project from that and see if that works for you. If it does it’s likely just a project property setting that is a bit off.